# How to create a string for a file path in C#?

Tags: .net

In the below code pls help me to setup a file path in asp.net ie C:\Search\City\Documents\file.txt

```
public string strName = "City";
public string strDocumentFolder = "Documents";
string file= "\\" + C:Search + "\\" + strName + "\\" + strDocumentFolder + "\\" + lbldoc.Text+"\\";
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the first `\\` in start and need `\\` after `c:` and before `Search`

```
string file=  "C:\\Search\\" + strName + "\\" + strDocumentFolder + "\\" + lbldoc.Text;
```

**Edit**

In the above we escaped the escape sequence character `backslash` with `backslash`. You can use the [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to avoid the backslash interpreted as escape sequence character.

[**String literals**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> A **regular string** literal consists of zero or more characters enclosed
>   in double quotes, as in "hello", and may include both simple escape
>   sequences (such as \t for the tab character) and hexadecimal and
>   Unicode escape sequences.
>
> A **verbatim string** literal consists of an @ character followed by a
>   double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing
>   double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim
>   string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted
>   verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence. In
>   particular, simple escape sequences and hexadecimal and Unicode escape
>   sequences are not processed in verbatim string literals. A verbatim
>   string literal may span multiple lines.

*Example*

```
string c = "hello \t world";               // hello     world
string d = @"hello \t world";               // hello \t world
```

Comment: i am trying to point out the file .when i debug it look like C:\Search\City\Documents\file.txt\ .how to remove \ when i tried it throws error

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options

1. Either use Server.MapPath
2. Path.Combine

e.g.

```
var fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
var fullPath = Server.MapPath(fileName);
```

Comment: how to use  var fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

Answer (score 0):

```
string file = @"C:\\Search" + "\\" + strName + "\\" + strDocumentFolder + "\\" + lbldoc.Text;
```

Comment: lbldoc.Text is not a constant i am passing the file name in this label

Comment: modified, is that you are looking for?